# How to restrict access to field setters of an object? Would achieving this with inheritance would be a bad choice?

Tags: java, inheritance, design-patterns, getter-setter, access-control

I have some business data objects that are created by the underlying services (say the data repository). These objects are created step by step. i.e (Step one only finds the image object from google, step two retrieves metadata about the image, step three downloads it to disk).

These same objects will be rendered in UI as they are being built. So the UI doesn't need to know anything about the setters and shouldn't have access to it.

But the services who are creating the instance, needs to have access to the setters. Please note that this model will be used from other packages so making setters package private is not a solution.

Here is the requirement in terms of code:
Image model:

```
class Image {
 private String src;
 public String getSrc(){
  return field;
 }
 public void setSrc(String src){
  return src;
 }
}
```

Service model:

```
interface IService {
 Image get(...);
 Image processMore(Image i);
}
```

UI/client code:

```
Image i = service.get(params);
render(i);
i = service.processMore(i);
render(i);
i.setSrc(null); //This is the problem. Client should not have access to this method.
```

**Possible solutions:**
**Solution 1: Interfacing**

```
public interface IImage{
 String getSrc();
}
interface IService {
     IImage get(...);
     IImage processMore(Image i);
    }
IImage i = service.get(params);
render(i);
i = service.processMore(i);//Casting IImage to Image - this cast can easily fail and no way to know IImage is always an Image
render(i);
```

Draw back: **Casting issue as I have commented**. Also a lot of boilerplate code will have to be written, for each object. This will get very complicated when Image model is extended.

**Solution 2: Builder pattern**
Again a lot of boilerplate code. But strictly speaking, Builder pattern does not fit here as the object is built in steps and we'll have to call getSrc() on a builder class, which probably violates something in the books.

**Solution 3: Inheritance**

```
public abstract class Image {
 protected String src;

 protected Image() {} //Ensure this class instance is never created
 public String getSrc(){
  return field;
 }
 protected void setSrc(String src){
  return src;
 }

 public static class Buildable extends Image {
  protected String src;

  public Buildable() {
   super();
  }

  @Override
  public void setSrc(String src){
   return src;
  }
 }
}

interface IService {
         Image get(...);
         Image processMore(Image.Buildable i);
        }
    Image i = service.get(params);
    render(i);
    i = service.processMore(i);//Casting Image to Image.Buildable - as Image constructor is protected and Image.Builder is public, only way to create Image is creating Image.Buildable and hence this cast should never fail.
    render(i);
```

So as a beginner who is learning SOLID principal, my question is,

1. **Does this inheritance model violates SOLID** (or other clean code guidelines)? If so how it should be done?

Comment: Can you not make the setters [package private](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)?

Comment: @Zephyr I was writing a whole answer involving design patterns and junk, but that seems so stupidly obvious now that I think about it!

Comment: You've called you original class ImmutableObject so I'm guessing you never plan for it to change. In that case, I would recommend either passing the necessary parameters through the constructor (and making your fields private final) or using the builder

Comment: @Zephyr i could but that would mean all services would need to reside on the same package. So essentially all my services would be inside com.example.model which i think is not very good for code maintenance given the fact i plan on adding multiple services and there are several models.

Comment: I guess the name immutable is misleading here. I do want it to change but only by the services or through ui or other clients.

Comment: I agree the builder pattern brings quite a lot of boiler plate, but I believe that's the only proper approach so that you can have "real immutable" objects (e.g. by finalising the class and the fields, plus using immutable types for fields). Lombok or the like can help reducing this boiler plate though.

Comment: @sp00m I'll take a look into Lombok. One argument against the builder pattern would be as I have mentioned is the service can never really finalize an object, at least until the end of processing, and the UI would need to access the fields way before that happens to notify the user exactly what is happening in the background, ie. did we find a picture? did we find metadata? is it downloading right now?